# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined? Next app using React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, html5-history

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined? Next app using React-Router

Upon searching for that error I came upon [people using Next's built in Router](https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught%20(in%20promise)%20TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27split%27%20of%20undefined%20at%20Router.onlyAHashChange&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS832US832&oq=Uncaught%20(in%20promise)%20TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27split%27%20of%20undefined%20at%20Router.onlyAHashChange%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.10778j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but they are using the [Next Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), while I am using [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)

This error occurs when the user navigates by using the browser's Back button.

Not sure what to post from my code, but this is what the error yields from `router.js`:

```
   onlyAHashChange(as) {
        if (!this.asPath)
            return false;
        const [oldUrlNoHash, oldHash] = this.asPath.split('#');
        const [newUrlNoHash, newHash] = as.split('#');
        // Makes sure we scroll to the provided hash if the url/hash are the same
        if (newHash && oldUrlNoHash === newUrlNoHash && oldHash === newHash) {
            return true;
        }
        // If the urls are change, there's more than a hash change
        if (oldUrlNoHash !== newUrlNoHash) {
            return false;
        }
        // If the hash has changed, then it's a hash only change.
        // This check is necessary to handle both the enter and
        // leave hash === '' cases. The identity case falls through
        // and is treated as a next reload.
        return oldHash !== newHash;
    }
```

Funny thing, I am using `BrowserRouter`. Specifically my `URL` profile looks like this:

`http://localhost:8016/login`

And the references in the code seem to be referencing something like this:

`http://localhost:8016#login`

**UPDATE**
After hearing and thinking about what Sheryl added to the discussion (see comments below) it promoted me to look into where the error was coming from more closely. Turns out it was in a package called `next-server`.

Comment: Try double checking that the typeof `asPath` and `as` are strings.

Comment: @programmerRaj Thanks my friend great idea! They're indeed strings!

Comment: What do you mean? Did you change it and make them strings or were they already strings. Also, does it work now?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with anything, but I'm confused by what you mean by this line: "I discovered it naturally while navigating with the browsers back button."?  I'm not sure if it's even relevant to your question, I'm only sure that I don't understand ;-)

Comment: @programmerRaj I didn't change them they were already strings...

Comment: @SherylHohman Hey there welcome! Well I guess I meant while building something which uses some traditional web functionality maybe one might mess around with the forward and back buttons in the browser? I thought it was pretty clear I was trying to get across that is where I discovered the bug??

Comment: Ok then. I think the relevant part, being how/when this bug presents itself. Perhaps rewording it to emphasize that aspect? "This error occurs when the user presses the browser's Back button."  As currently worded, it seems either ambiguous as to what you're referring to (eg the other posts, or why you chose React-Router over Next's Router..), or irrelevant (eg your personal journey, as opposed to how/when/why the bug (always, yet the only time, it) presents itself), IMHO.  Thanks for clarifying. And Good Luck! Sorry, I dunno the answer.